# Extracting data from a csv file using php

Tags: php, csv

I wrote this piece of code:

```
$handle = fopen('upload/EFT.csv', "r");  
   while (! feof($handle)) { 
    print_r(fgetcsv($handle));
    }
fclose($handle);
```

This is the file:

```
AKRV0002,AKR,V0002,Akron
AKRV0006,AKR,V0006,Akron
AKRV0007,AKR,V0007,Akron
AKRV0011,AKR,V0011,Akron
AKRV0012,AKR,V0012,Akron
ATLV0019,ATL,V0019,ATLANTA
ATLV0021,ATL,V0021,ATLANTA
```

It returns this:

```
Array ( [0] => AKRV0002 [1] => AKR [2] => V0002 [3] => Akron AKRV0006 [4] => AKR [5] => V0006 [6] => Akron AKRV0007 [7] => AKR [8] => V0007 [9] => Akron AKRV0011 [10] => AKR [11] => V0011 [12] => Akron AKRV0012 [13] => AKR [14] => V0012 [15] => Akron ATLV0019 [16] => ATL [17] => V0019 [18] => ATLANTA ATLV0021 [19] => ATL [20] => V0021 [21] => ATLANTA
```

How can I have this return each line in a new array?

Answer (score 4):

See how array position 3 is "Akron AKRV0006" — that is the last value of **line 1** and the first value of **line 2**. It appears that the newlines aren't being read correctly.  Without your raw file, I can't tell why.

Once you have fixed that, you will see that [fgetcsv](http://php.net/fgetcsv) reads only one line at a time (in other words, returns an array with the data from **only one row**), not all lines at once.  So, you will need to loop and add each array to another array until fgetcsv returns no more data:

```
$data = array();
while ($row = fgetcsv($handle)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: The csv file was saved from within excel, is there a special way of saving it?  Can you give me some pointers on this?

Comment: @MG1 You can try reading it as a raw string and outputting the raw ASCII code of each character, and seeing what characters fall between those values.  Alternatively, you can type up a brand new file in your text editor and see if that gives you different results.

Answer (score 1):

Do you happen to use an old Mac computer?

"Note: If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the auto_detect_line_endings run-time configuration option may help resolve the problem."

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: Nope, I'm using a brand new mac computer.  I saved the file as csv from excel.  Is there a special way of saving the file?