# PHP for read txt file line just upon sign "#"

Tags: php, text-files, filehandle

I have this txt file structure:

```
"data";"data";"data";#;"my data";"my data";"my data"
"data";"data";"data";#;"my data";"my data";"my data"
"data";"data";"data";#;"my data";"my data";"my data"
```

I need to read this file data just after the # sign.
My PHP code just for read the entire line.

```
$file_handle = fopen("texto.txt", "r");
$numlinha = 0;
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
   $line = fgets($file_handle);
   $numlinha++;
   echo $numlinha . ". " . $line . "</br></br>";
}
fclose($file_handle);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extracting data from a csv file using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968073/extracting-data-from-a-csv-file-using-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract data from a CSV file in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805427/how-to-extract-data-from-csv-file-in-php/2805486#2805486)

Comment: And in case you really want the full text after the #, http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [strpos](http://php.net/function.strpos) function to find position of first # char in your line.

```
$file_handle = fopen("texto.txt", "r");
$numlinha = 0;
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
   $line = fgets($file_handle);
   $cpos = strpos($line, '#');
   if ($cpos !== FALSE) {
       $line = substr($line, 0, $cpos);
   }
   $numlinha++;
   echo $numlinha . ". " . $line . "</br></br>";
}
fclose($file_handle);
```

Comment: Thanks to all. Very useful tips.
One more thing, can I put each data value on a $_SESSION variable and give names like $_SESSION['peso'] for the first $_SESSION['clientID'] for the second...?

Answer (score 1):

```
$file_handle = fopen("texto.txt", "r");
$numlinha = 0;
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
   $line = fgets($file_handle);
   $parts = explode("#", $line);
   $parts[0] // part before the # in this line
   $parts[1] // part behind the # in this line
   $numlinha++;
   echo $numlinha . ". " . $line . "</br></br>";
}
fclose($file_handle);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:
    $data = explode(";#;", $line);
And then do your processing on $data[1] instead of $line.

This assumes that ;#; is unique on each line...

Note that using string position testing (strpos()) and substr() to extract the part of the string would be more resource consuming, I believe, than just taking the line you already read and splitting it at the exact known delimiter, which in this case is ;#;.

The other examples posted assume that # will be only on the line once, or at least the divide will be the first # in the line. Using ;#; would make it more unique, and your result can be processed by the str_getcsv() function if you needed to break it down into an array of values for other uses.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the explode function, to split the string in two parts using the "#" delimiter

http://php.net/function.explode